# How do I ref a var of type map in Heredoc string

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a map like this:

```
variable somemap {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    somekey = "abc"
  }
}
```

And I have this in my tf module:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "role_name" {
  name = "RoleName"
  assume_role_policy = <<-TRUSTPOLICY
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
          },
          "Action": [
            "sts:AssumeRole",
            "sts:TagSession"
          ],
          "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
              "aws:PrincipalArn": [
                "${var.somemap["somekey"]}",
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  TRUSTPOLICY
}
```

But running this I get an error:

> "assume_role_policy" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character ']'

A reference to a map is done like this:

```
var.somemap["somekey"]
```

My feeling is that terraform got an issue with the ["somekey"] in heredocs files. But I cant find anything on it.
I have also test to use the lookup function but getting the same error. And I cant see any syntax error to the policy document.

Is it possible to use a maps reference in a heredoc string and if so how?

Comment: You can try with `"aws:PrincipalArn": [ var.somemap.somekey ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not related to the interpolation sequence, but to the invalid JSON syntax just after it. If you replace the interpolation temporarily with a literal value it might be easier to notice:

```
              "aws:PrincipalArn": [
                "placeholder",
              ]
```

Notice the comma just before the closing bracket, which is invalid JSON syntax. If you remove that comma then your resulting string will hopefully be valid JSON *as long as `var.somemap` doesn't include any characters that would need escaping in JSON*.

---

For a more robust approach I would suggest using [`jsonencode`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode) to produce the entire string. Generating JSON by string concatenation is hard to get correct, but if you use `jsonencode` then Terraform will be the one to produce the JSON syntax and so you only need to worry about providing a suitable data structure to encode.

```
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          AWS = "*"
        }
        Action = [
          "sts:AssumeRole",
          "sts:TagSession",
        ]
        Condition = {
          StringLike = {
            "aws:PrincipalArn" = [
              var.somemap["somekey"],
            ]
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  })
```

With the above example Terraform will be the one to parse and evaluate the argument to `jsonencode`, producing a value in the Terraform language type system, and then the `jsonencode` function will convert that to JSON using the conversion rules described in the `jsonencode` documentation, guaranteeing that the result will be valid JSON syntax, with both correct string escaping and with commas only in the places where JSON expects them to be.

Comment: Thanks for the tips with jsonencode. And typical it was a comma that was the issue, thanks for your sharp eyes :)